# File dialog not working with PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qfiledialog

This is my first time attempting to create a GUI. I have created a simple program with a button that is supposed to open the file browser and return that file. I know PyQt5 has some built in file dialog commands, but they are not working for me. I attempted to use the tutorial found on https://pythonspot.com/en/pyqt5-file-dialog/. I also tried several other approaches from online. I cannot think of a reason why it is not working.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1082, 800)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile)


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))


    # FUNCTION BELOW NOT WORKING
    def openFile(self):   
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
    if fileName:
        print(fileName)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getOpenFileName` requires as a parameter an object of type `QWidget`, in your case Ui_Form is not of that type.

- **First Solution**: pass `None`:

---

```
fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
```

- **Second solution**: create a class that implements the Ui_Form visa, and in it the openFile slot is created.

---

```
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile)

    def openFile(self):   
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)
```

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: I also found another solution (which I posted below). What is the difference in functionality between the two solutions?

Comment: @J.Doe what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a QWidget as the parent. I modified your code to save the `Form` and use that later.

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.Form = Form          # <-----
        ...

    def openFile(self):   
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.Form,    # <-----
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I found was to change the function to:

```
def openFileNameDialog(self):    
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    self.ui.lineEdit.setText(fname)
```